# Laravel : Filtering Eloquent Collections by unique column value after retrieval

Tags: php, database, laravel, eloquent

From the laravel docs we know that we can filter Eloquent collections after retrieval from database by applying a filter :

```
$users = $users->filter(function($user)
{
    return $user->isAdmin();
});
```

Does anyone knows if we can filter the collections by a unique column/attribute that is not the primary key?

**Edited:** Say I have an column `slug` and I want to filter the collection based on distinct `slug` values , removing duplicates along the way.

Comment: On what column would you like to filter? Can you give a bit more information?

Comment: So, You just want all the distinct slugs? Or do you want to get the user data as well? In that case, do you want the first user or another user with this data?

Comment: @Jerodev yes i still need the user data but only the first user with the distinct slug. the rest can be removed

Comment: Why not do it by using MySQL's `distinct` operator?

Comment: @VitKos because i do have other filtered collection that I need to pass to the view. running MySQL's distinct operator would mean that i need 2 queries

Comment: Not sure how it really works, but you can try to use a `unique()` operator over your collection. You can find the supporting docs here: http://laravel.com/api/4.1/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Collection.html#method_unique

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old but you could try something like this:

```
$existingSlugs = [];
$users = $users->filter(function($user) use (&$existingSlugs)
{
    $duplicate = in_array($user->slug, $existingSlugs);
    if(!$duplicate) {
        $existingSlugs[] = $user->slug;
    }
    return !$duplicate;
});
```